# Vertical space from the edge of the page

Tags: spacing, formatting, vertical-alignment, text, edge

How make vertical space from the edge of the page or the top margin, eg. second paragraph lipsum

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]    

\vspace{100pt}  %<-What should i write here? 

\lipsum[2]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: I set margins, but i want do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=30.5mm, vmargin=26.5mm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
```

%something to set distance (green X on picture) between start lipsum2 and edge of the page or edge of top margin

```
\lipsum[2]
```

%something to set distance (orange Y on picture) between start lipsum3 and edge of the page or edge of top margin

```
\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en) or call `texdoc geometry` from a terminal.

Comment: For all your pages?

Comment: See edit please

Answer (score 3):

Solution of the strange text positioning via `zref-savepos`. Three LaTeX runs are needed, because the positions are recorded via the `.aux` file mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=30.5mm, vmargin=26.5mm}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcommand*{\SpaceX}{30mm}
\newcommand*{\SpaceY}{.5\paperheight}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\zsavepos{1-2}
\kern\dimexpr-\paperheight+\zposy{1-2}sp+\SpaceX\relax

\lipsum[2]

\zsavepos{2-3}
\kern\dimexpr-\paperheight+\zposy{2-3}sp+\SpaceY\relax

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]